# I am having trouble using jquery to submit a form. It was working before;/

Tags: php, jquery

When a user clicks a link it uses jquery ajax to submit a form to go to paypal. It is not working for some reason. I appreciate any help.

The HTML link:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:go_paypal();">Paypal</a>
```

The JS function:

```
function go_paypal() {

data = 'req_paypal=1';

$.blockUI({ message: '<h1> Going to Paypal...</h1>',css:{background:'#000'} });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: data,
      success: function(data) { $("#paypal_form").html(data); $("#payPalForm").submit(); } ,
      error: function() {$.unblockUI(); alert('Unable to communicate to server.'); }
    }); 
    return false;
}
```

The PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['req_paypal']) && $_POST['req_paypal'] == 1 ) {


    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `transactions` (id,type,ip,time,ammount,status) VALUES (NULL,1,\''.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'\',\''.time().'\',\''.$global['paypal_prod_amount'].'\',0) ';
    echo $sql;
//      $sql2 = 'INSERT INTO `users` (id,email,password,referred_by,referrals) VALUES ('',)';

    mysql_query($sql);

    $id = mysql_insert_id();

    $html = '
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payPalForm">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="One Year of Imgur Pro">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="'.$global['paypal_email'].'">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'.base64_encode($id).'">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="'.$global['paypal_return'].'">
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" id="item_name" value="One Year of Imgur Pro" >
<input name="amount" type="hidden" id="amount" value="'.$global['paypal_prod_amount'].'" >
</form>
    ';

    echo $html;exit;
}
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate more in developer's perspective, not in an enduser-like "It's not working!" perspective. What exactly happens? What happens not? What code got executed? What code not?

Comment: PS: while in the message editor, please read the right hand column how to format code (and the preview block at the bottom of the page). I've fixed it for you (two times).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. This was my first time submitting an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data object must be a json object, not a string.

try this:

```
function go_paypal() {
    data = { req_paypal: 1 };

    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1> Going to Paypal...</h1>', css:{background:'#000'} });
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "index.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(data) { $("#paypal_form").html(data).submit(); } ,
          error: function() { $.unblockUI(); alert('Unable to communicate to server.'); }
        });
}
```

i would also suggest to change the a tag to

```
$("#go_paypal").click(function() { go_paypal(); }
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:go_paypal();">Paypal</a>
```

that way the page wont be scrolled to the top when the link is clicked

Comment: Here's what worked. Thanks for checking @GerManson

function go_paypal() {

var postData = {req_paypal:1};

$.blockUI({ message: '<h1> Going to Paypal...</h1>',css:{background:'#000'} });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: postData,
      success: function(data) {$(document.body).append(data);$("#payPalForm").submit(); } ,
      error: function() {$.unblockUI(); alert('Unable to communicate to server.'); }
    }); 
    return false;
}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like inside your `success` function, you are passing the **global** variable `data` to `html()`. Try naming your vars a bit more carefully.

Try this:

```
function go_paypal() {

var postData = 'req_paypal=1';

$.blockUI({ message: '<h1> Going to Paypal...</h1>',css:{background:'#000'} });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: postData,
      success: function(data) { $("#paypal_form").html(data); $("#payPalForm").submit(); },
      error: function(e) {$.unblockUI(); alert('Unable to communicate to server.'); }
    }); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I changed the variable to what you suggested and it's still not working. Any other suggestions? What other information can I add to help solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the problem here seems very vague since we don't know what really isn't working. My basic recommendation to find out what is not working is to turn on error reporting in PHP and then print copious amounts of output at each step of the process. Print variable values at each step to see if they are what you think they should be. Print messages to let you know when you enter a subroutine, etc. This will help narrow down where something goes wrong. Often, you will find that you just mistyped something.

I see the array $global, but it doesn't seem to be defined. Did you mean $GLOBALS? I would suspect that is the problem. If you turn your error reporting on in PHP while testing, you should see some complaints about an undefined variable. Also, while testing, double check all of your values and be sure to fuzz test. Some problems might not be apparent until too late to fix once it goes live.

Comment: Is there any way I can email you or message you on gtalk / aim / skype?

Comment: Ps. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: @noah, StackOverflow is design for all of your contact on an issue to be done on this page. That means that if someone else has the same issue, then any tips will be visible to them.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts, makes sense but trying to get real time responses. I'll limit myself to posting questions here. I guess public / social is the future.

Answer (score 1):

First I would try to add a input submit to the form in PHP and also try that form in the code without fetching via ajax and in Firebug execute the submit code $("#payPalForm").submit(); to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Um... did you try: `<a href="javascript:go_paypal();">Paypal</a>` I had the same problem and it was the a's onclick handler... So if this doesnt work dont give me -1 i was just trying to help based on my previous experience. =)

Comment: I won't down rate you for taking the time to try. That didn't work. It's strange since I can see the data posting, http://skitch.com/okdork/dnwm1/get-your-favorite-websites-at-up-to-80-off-appsumo.com 

but I can't understand why the form isn't submitting still...